# Why the initialization script ... .gradle does not exist?

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle

This is a React Native project and I use plain RN cli, not Expo.

The `android/build.gradle` file gives an error. On the first line I see a red tilde. When I hover over it I get the following message.

```js
Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 

'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-all.zip'.

The specified initialization script 

'/var/folders/n_/yd13xnrj4cxbvk7yvrz84m1w0000gp/T/d146c9752a26f79b52047fb6dc6ed385d064e120494f96f08ca63a317c41f94c.gradle' 

does not exist.
```

What I've tried:

1. Use other gradle version and plugin.
2. Clean `./gradle/caches` and `./gradle/daemon` and `./gradle/native` and `./gradle/notifications` and `./gradle/wrapper/dists`.
3. Sync Project with Gradle files (In Android Studio)
4. Delete `node_modules` and `npm install`
5. Close project. Then, when I reopen the project (in VSCode) I get a message in the terminal: `Opening Java Projects` => which in details it says: `Importing Gradle projects...` When this is done, the tilde in the `build.gradle` file appears.

Additional notes:

The app runs fine in emulator, but when I upload it to Google Play Console, the app is suspended. The pre-launch report gives the following crashes:

```js
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. 

Make sure you're either running Metro (run 'npx react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.
```

```js
java.lang.SecurityException: No active admin ComponentInfo{com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin.DeviceAdminReceiver}
```

- Android Gradle Plugin Version: 7.4.1
- Gradle Version: 7.5.1

Here is the output of `npx react-native info`

```js
System:
    OS: macOS 12.6.6
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770HQ CPU @ 2.20GHz
    Memory: 41.13 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.18.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.1/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.10 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 9.6.6 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.1/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2023.05.15.00 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 22.2, iOS 16.2, macOS 13.1, tvOS 16.1, watchOS 9.1
    Android SDK:
      Android NDK: 22.1.7171670
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2022.1 AI-221.6008.13.2211.9514443
    Xcode: 14.2/14C18 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.19 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 18.1.0 => 18.1.0 
    react-native: 0.70.6 => 0.70.6 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

Comment: Can you run `npx react-native info` in your terminal? Also what version of gradle do you have set up inside the project? You can check it inside `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` - `distributionUrl`

Comment: Hi @NuttyJackJ! About info check the updated question above. - Android Gradle Plugin Version: 7.4.1
- Gradle Version: 7.5.1

Comment: Can you make sure you have the gradlew-wrapper.properties distribution url to be as follows: `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-all.zip`

Comment: Yes it is: `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-all.zip`

Comment: Should I delete the android folder, create a new project take the android folder and paste it to the old...?

Comment: If you are able to run a new sample react-native app by default, it means your machine is set-up properly, so the issue you have is a project configuration issue. Try that and see if it works for you. Also don't forget to add native specific configuration that you have added to your project (build.gradle, MainApplication, MainActivity ...), , in addition to changing app bundle id.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I'm Using expo cli

I was having the same issue. What worked partially is that I deleted the .expo folder with all its components and uploaded file to the EAS server using

```
eas build -p android
```

and then wait for the files to be uploaded to EAS server. When the build is completed, just upload the .aab file to playstore.

This works but you cannot change the version number and other settings in the MANIFEST file

Make sure that you have the latest eas version installed. You can use the following command

```
npm i --global eas-cli
```

Comment: Hello @Muhammad! Thank you for your solution, but I forgot to mention I use plain RN cli, not expo. Maybe your solution will help someone else, though.

Comment: Should I delete the android folder, create a new project take the android folder and paste it to the old...?